# How to update current view of viewpager?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I'm performing on click on current button to change its background color and it is changing the next page button background 
basically I want when user clicks on any of  4 options of the question if it is correct change it to green otherwise red but it is changing the background of next page button 
and even if I'm clicking on option1  and showing toast to get text of that option it is showing the text of next page option1 
what should I do help me please.

```
package com.app.apti.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.app.apti.R;
import com.app.apti.model.QuestionData;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class QuestionViewPager extends PagerAdapter {


LinearLayout option1color,option2color,option3color,option4color;
TextView option1,option2,option3,option4,ques,questionno;
private Context context;
ArrayList<QuestionData> question;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ImageView imageView;
String category;

public QuestionViewPager(Context context, ArrayList<QuestionData> 
question,String category)
{
    this.context=context;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.question=question;
    this.category=category;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(question != null){
        return question.size();
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.questionlayout, container, false);
    option1color=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewWithId(R.id.color_option1);
    option2color=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.color_option2);
    option3color=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.color_option3);
    option4color=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.color_option4);

    option1=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option1);
    option2=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option2);
    option3=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option3);
    option4=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option4);
    ques=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ques);
    questionno=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.questionno);

    questionno.setText(position+1+"/"+getCount());
    ques.setText(Html.fromHtml(question.get(position).getQues()));
    option1.setText(Html.fromHtml(question.get(position).getOpt1()));
    option2.setText(Html.fromHtml(question.get(position).getOpt2()));
    option3.setText(Html.fromHtml(question.get(position).getOpt3()));
    option4.setText(Html.fromHtml(question.get(position).getOpt4()));

    option1color.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(context,option1.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(question.get(position).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(option1.getText().toString()))
            {

                option1color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_green);
            }else
            {
                option1color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_red);

            }
        }
    });
    option2color.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(question.get(position).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(option2.getText().toString()))
            {
                option2color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_green);
            }else
            {
                option2color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_red);

            }
        }
    });
    option3color.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(question.get(position).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(option3.getText().toString()))
            {
                option3color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_green);
            }else
            {
                option3color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_red);

            }
        }
    });
    option4color.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(question.get(position).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(option4.getText().toString()))
            {
                option4color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_green);
            }else
            {
                option4color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_red);

            }
        }
    });

    container.addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happening because

```
LinearLayout option1color,option2color,option3color,option4color;
TextView option1,option2,option3,option4,ques,questionno;
```

are fields and their values will be set to the last values set in the last call of `instantiateItem`. So when the on click callback is called, they just get the last assigned values. Just make them local variable within the `instantiateItem` method body and you should be fine.

Full code:

```
package com.app.apti.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.app.apti.R;
import com.app.apti.model.QuestionData;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class QuestionViewPager extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
ArrayList<QuestionData> question;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ImageView imageView;
String category;

public QuestionViewPager(Context context, ArrayList<QuestionData> 
question,String category)
{
    this.context=context;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.question=question;
    this.category=category;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(question != null){
        return question.size();
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    /* ALL LOCAL VARIABLES */
    LinearLayout option1color,option2color,option3color,option4color;
    TextView option1,option2,option3,option4,ques,questionno;

    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.questionlayout, container, false);
    option1color=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewWithTag(R.id.color_option1);
    option2color=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.color_option2);
    option3color=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.color_option3);
    option4color=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.color_option4);

    option1=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option1);
    option2=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option2);
    option3=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option3);
    option4=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option4);
    ques=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ques);
    questionno=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.questionno);

    questionno.setText(position+1+"/"+getCount());
    ques.setText(Html.fromHtml(question.get(position).getQues()));
    option1.setText(Html.fromHtml(question.get(position).getOpt1()));
    option2.setText(Html.fromHtml(question.get(position).getOpt2()));
    option3.setText(Html.fromHtml(question.get(position).getOpt3()));
    option4.setText(Html.fromHtml(question.get(position).getOpt4()));

    option1color.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,option1.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(question.get(position).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(option1.getText().toString()))
            {

                option1color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_green);
            }else
            {
                option1color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_red);

            }
        }
    });
    option2color.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(question.get(position).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(option2.getText().toString()))
            {
                option2color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_green);
            }else
            {
                option2color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_red);

            }
        }
    });
    option3color.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(question.get(position).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(option3.getText().toString()))
            {
                option3color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_green);
            }else
            {
                option3color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_red);

            }
        }
    });
    option4color.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(question.get(position).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(option4.getText().toString()))
            {
                option4color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_green);
            }else
            {
                option4color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_red);

            }
        }
    });

    container.addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}



}
```

Comment: now i getting this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: It shouldn't have, could be other issues. Can you share the exact error log? Also remove `notifyDataSetChanged();` from the `onClickListener`. Updated the code.

Comment: Awesome!! As a suggestion, the code that is written inside `instantiateItem` finding the view by id and setting listeners you should move it to a utility class, maybe wrap it inside a static method. That way you will add separation of concerns, better decoupling, and more robust code. Just a suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can using interface. Whenever user give answer for any question you can create callback form adapter class using interface implementation on particular pager's activity or fragment. based on that callback you can touch the view and change the background as per question's answer is either right or wrong.

Happy coding!!. If any query let me know.

Comment: hey can you give example i am new to android

Comment: Yes but currently i didn't have any example i have to make it for you but will provide after some time.

Answer (score 0):

```
viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            updatePage(i); //a dummy method to do 
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
        }
    });

private void updateFab(int selectedPage) {
    switch (selectedPage) {
        case MainPagerAdapter.POS1:
            showToast();
            break;
        case MainPagerAdapter.POS2:
           hideToast();
            break;
        case MainPagerAdapter.POS3:
           showToast();
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

where, MainPagerAdapter extends FragPagerADapter and

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case POS1:
        return FragOne.newInstance();
    case POS2:
        return FragTwo.newInstance();
    case POS2:
        return FragThree.newInstance();
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for the silly question updatePage(i); what should i write here

Comment: Here you define whatever you want to do in your code - update background color or update list contents on that page.

Comment: i mean how  can i get a reference of view of that layout